# Different PHP directory Apache + CLI (chrooted)

Tags: php, linux, apache, plesk, chroot

I have an issue running php command line tasks on chrooted environment. (CentOS Linux running Plesk 11.5)

If I execute the following php code:

```
<?php 
    echo getcwd();
?>
```

On web server (Apache + suexec + php fastcgi) it prints:

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs
```

On command line (/bin/bash/ chrooted):

```
/httpdocs
```

The directory difference breaks some PHP applications. 
Can I configure apache or php to avoid this? Anyone knows?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: Also I have root access to the server

Comment: why not use dirname(__FILE__) instead to obtain the current folder?

Comment: Same result with: <?php echo dirname(__FILE__) ?>

Comment: that should give you the *absolute path* to the running file.

Comment: I know, but in a chrooted shell the absolute path is /httpdocs. I think it's not a problem at php code level, I think i'm missing some configuration on chroot environment, apache or php.

Comment: Check the users under which the application is running, both on the CLI and on the web server; they should be different. In such case, simply run both under the same user. That should ensure that both give you the same paths.

Comment: Both are running with the same user (mydomain).
Apache is working with suexec and php fastcgi.

Comment: Are you sure Apache isn't running under root? You do use *sudo* to start/stop it, right? And unless you logged in under root, the CLI user would be different.

Comment: this is the top command output: 
30383 **mydomain**      20   0  341m  35m 9956 S 28.6  0.3   0:01.46 **php-cgi**

Comment: The following php code on the web server "<?php system('whoami') ?>" prints "mydomain".

Comment: hmm....it's unusual to have the same user running the same process under two different root folders. Either the users are different or the applications are; the problem's got to be one of the two.

Comment: If you have root access, undo the chroot.

Comment: It happens because the user shell is "/bin/bash (chrooted)". I think i'm missing some configuration but I don't know what. I've been searching for days on google.

Comment: I have root access but I cant grant ssh access to the other users without chroot because it's dangerous.

Comment: If you cannot disable chroot, then your app has to be adjusted with chrooted path when called from shell. Some sort of code modification will be required. I don't think there can be a way to have chroot and not have chrooted path.

Comment: And what about have chrooted path on php over apache? It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a dirty trick with symlinks:

```
# cd /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/
# ln -s httpdocs var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs
```

And then:

```
$ php /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/test.php
```